Duplicate input field content into another field simultaneosuly
First off, this seems like a very simple question, but, the solutions I've found so far haven't worked, they are mostly suggesting using jQuery, but, as I'm using Bootstrap 5, they have moved away from jQuery, so I'm hoping not to use that in favour of JavaScript if possible, or even just HTML if that is a thing.
Basically, my issue is that I have an input field in an off-canvas settings area. When a user types anything in that field, I want that number to then appear on the body of the HTML in the form of another text field or something. This could happen either as they are typing, updating per key-press or with a submit button, either would work fine. I have included a screenshot to better explain what I mean:

I have artificially added the Text Here on the left to help give a visual on what I would like to achieve, at the moment entering the text in the Centre ID No. field does nothing.
If anybody can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers.
Edit:
Solved! This is what I did:
HTML:
<h1 id="output">Text Goes Here</h1>

<div>
  <span>Centre ID No.</span>
   <input type="text" id="centreNumber"/>
</div>

In my JavaScript file:
const output = document.getElementById("output");

document.getElementById("centreNumber").addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  output.textContent = e.target.value;
});

Apologies if there is unnecessary information here, I'm new to a lot of this and kinda just feeling my way around for now. Appreciate all the help!

Use keyup and paste event listeners on the field the user types into. It can copy the value to the other field.

The keywords here are "keyup"  and "value"

Please post the relevant HTML, CSS and JavaScript that you have so we can help you.

You can also use the input event. It will fire when the value of the input element changes, so that can be either by typing or pasting using the context menu with the mouse.


const output = document.getElementById('output');

document.forms.form01.id.addEventListener('input', e => {
  output.textContent = e.target.value;
})
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
<h1 id="output"></h1>
<form name="form01">
  <label>Centre ID No. <input type="text" name="id"></label>
</form>




document.forms is an ancient way to access a form element using the BOM. Instead, use the DOM API with document.querySelector().

@ScottMarcus To be fair, it isn't deprecated though

@nikk You can't deprecate something that was never a standard.

Thank you, @ScottMarcus and chrwahl, using a combination of your suggestions I've got it working beautifully. I will edit my post to show what I did.

@ScottMarcus Looks to be defined here
